# iOS - Double Tap Gesture does not work on top of a UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview, swipe-gesture

I have a `viewController` that has several items added programatically. A `UILabel` and a `UIWebView` including a scroll view.

Now I have added a swipe gesture onto the viewController using storyboard and when run all seems ok.

The issue comes when I try to swipe over the the `UIWebview`, it does not trigger the the Swipe gesture and looks as if its cancelling  it out.

How can i enable it so the gesture works over the whole view but yet keeping the `UIWebview` functionality?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can set
[UIWebView.scrollView setDelegate:myViewController]
and implement in your view controller
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender

But to really pass events, you will need more:
http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks for this I will look at this when I get back in and let you know. Much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is what i am after I want it so that when i Dbl tap on the screen the gesture actives as set by the storyboard settings, but when i tap over a web view it does not work somehow the web view overrider my tap gesture..?